# Make a tag for exceptions as a programming construct?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There exists an [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception) tag, but a search over the tag reveals that it is used for two very different things.  About half of the questions seem to be about the concept and usage of exception handling constructs.  The other half of questions seem to be about someone having an exception in their code, and needing debugging assistance.

Does there currently exist a way to distinguish between these two things in search?  Is there a better tag for "help with errors" that I could be pointing people to (or vice-versa, a tag for "exception handling constructs")?

Comment: Given that the tag has 48k+ questions, splitting it in two would be a ton of work.

Comment: @BDL I'm not familiar with the tag doing-stuff-to process.  Is there a place I can go to learn more about how tags are split, burninated and whatever else?

Comment: [Burnination is explained here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination). For splitting, there is no formal process. But I guess if we split a tag, then we also have to go over all existing questions in the tag and retag where appropriate. That means checking the 48k questions by hand.

Comment: Using [exception] along with a primary language tag is fine to tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [exception-handing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception-handing) which is unfortunately synonymous with [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception) and [exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exceptions). The first one is far more unambiguous. I would indeed suspect there's a lot of questions improperly tagged [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception) as in: I have a program crash. (To make things worse, there's also hardware exceptions, which has quite a different meaning from exception handling.)

Disambiguate [exception-handing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception-handing) and [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception) would be a good idea, perhaps. If it can be easily done, which I doubt. There's a vast amount of questions to go through, the benefit isn't worth the work effort.

So I'd rather dismiss it as a lost cause. Because when looking for info about exceptions, you don't use that generic tag, but rather a specific one.

Comment: The tag info is pretty good and seems to be exactly what OP wants. It's just that the usage doesn't follow that description. Which...isn't very surprising.

Comment: Would it be useful to reverse the direction of the synonyms, making [exception-handling] the “master” tag? That’s much easier than a disambuguation, and I agree that it might be a better tag description.

Comment: @CodyGray I think all that matters is what the site suggest when you post a new question. That is, what pops up when you type "exception" in the tag field.